# Basic C language task about printing a certain number using %.3f

Tags: c

i just started studying programming at school, and i am so lost already. Here's the task:

**Answer all 3 tasks in a separate file and return it.
What is the result if the format string (control character) of the printf function is %.3f and the number to be printed is
456.87654321
0.17023
443.14159**

How do i even do this? My code is this but it's obviously wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int num1, num2, num3;

printf("Give a number 1\n");
scanf("%i", &num1);

printf("Answer is on %.3f", &num1);

return 0;

}
```

It gave me 0 as answers or 0.000 what ever. Only 0's.

I don't know what to do really, my teacher is already on another subject and has no time helping me much.

Comment: Do you know the difference between an `int` and a `float`? Do you know what `&` does?

Comment: Erm.. int is a whole number and float is decimals.. right? And idk what that symbol is.

Comment: `double d = 456.87654321; printf("%.3f\n", d);`

Comment: Good. Note that the format specifiers must match the types of the parameters when using `printf` or `scanf`.

Comment: More to the point, your variables are ints, but you're using a floating format string "%.3f" to print it (and worse, you're trying to print the address of the int rather than its value).

Comment: `printf()` does not want the address of the variable; it wants the value (when you figure out the difference between an `int` and a `float`...) This is extremely basic and must be covered in the early chapters of your course material.

Comment: Ah.. should have figured this. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know what the `&` does yet, don't use it... unless you're using `scanf`, in which case for mysterious reasons you do need it, unless you're using `%s`, in which case you don't... (There's a reason C is not generally considered a good teaching language...)

Comment: Task is done. I hope this is right: #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
double d = 456.87654321, b = 0.17023, z = 443.14159;

printf("d answer is %.3f, ja b answer is %.3f, ja z answer is %.3f", d, b, z);

    return 0;
}

It looks good to me, thank you guys so much i appreciate it.

Comment: @DirtyFan2: Please press the "Help" button when writing a comment to learn how to put code into a comment.

Comment: Oh sorry, new here x)

Answer (score 0):

This source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%.3f\n", 456.87654321);
    printf("%.3f\n", 0.17023);
    printf("%.3f\n", 443.14159);
}
```

produces this output:

```
456.877
0.170
443.142
```

Comment: How did you do all this and get the correct answers without adding any variables?? This seems pretty fast way to do this task. This is my way of doing it, am i doing it ok or can i improve it better? 


#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
double d = 456.87654321, b = 0.17023, z = 443.14159;

printf("d answer is %.3f, ja b answer is %.3f, ja z answer is %.3f", d, b, z);

    return 0;
}

What does void mean? My teacher said we don't need it now ( might come later in our course idk ). 

Also thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `num1` to be an `int` (integer... whole numbers only).

Then you read that number from the keyboard.
I'm guessing you're entering `456.87654321`.
*(hint, that is **not** a whole number. it will not fit in an `int`)*

Then you try to print it out with:

```
printf("Answer is on %.3f", &num1);
```

This has *several* problems.

- `%.3f` is for printing out doubles, not ints.
- You passed the "address" (`&` sign) of the number you wanted to print.
   Just pass the variable directly

---

Fixing up your code, I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double num1;                       // Declare DOUBLE, not INT

    printf("Give a number 1\n");
    scanf("%f", &num1);                // Get a DOUBLE from input, not an INT

    printf("Answer is on %.3f", num1); // Remove the & (address)

    return 0;
}
```